# Object bubble sorting error: NullPointerException

Tags: java, exception, null

When trying to bubble sort an array of objects something seems to be reading as null however it appears it is not null
What is being read as null?

```
for(int i =0; i<(count-1); i++)
 {
     for(int j=(i+1);i<count;j++)
     {
         if((books[j].getAuthor()).compareTo((books[i].getAuthor()))>0)
         {
             temp = books[i];
             books[i] = books[j];
             books[j] = temp;



         }

     }

 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are checking `i` instead of `j` in the inner cycle. So change this:

```
for(int j=(i+1);i<count;j++)
```

to this:

```
for(int j=(i+1);j<count;j++)
```